# Total de nós de uma árvore binária perfeita

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Tenho uma árvore binária perfeita de altura 10, qual é o cálculo para descobrir a quantidade de nós?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simples e rápido:

Para descobrirmos a *quantidade de nós* de uma arvore binária cheia, usamos a formula:

```
n = 2 ^ (h + 1) - 1
```

Sendo:

- ***n*** a quantidade nós e,
- ***h*** a altura da árvore.

Ou seja, no seu exemplo ficará:

```
n = 2 ^ (10 + 1) - 1
n = 2 ^ (11) - 1
n = 2048 - 1
n = 2047
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/9/93/ArvoresBin%C3%A1rias_Parte2.pdf, fórmula para esse cálculo é:

N = 2^h - 1

N = 2^10 - 1

N = 1024 - 1

N = 1023